# Get Index of JComboBox in another class

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am trying to have different Events on a button click, which are dependent on the index of a JComboBox. Since the actual project is larger than the example the two pieces of code are in different classes:

```
public class GUI {

    private String[] difficultyStrings = {"Easy", "Middle", "Hard"};

    private JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel();

    private JButton button = new JButton();

    private JComboBox<String> diffucltyBox = new JComboBox(difficultyStrings);

   public static void main(String[] args) {

        GUI guiObject = new GUI();
        guiObject.setGUI();
    }

    private void setGUI() {

        Problem problemObject = new Problem();

        button.setText("What index is selected?");
        button.addActionListener(e -> {

            problemObject.actions();
        });

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(diffucltyBox);

        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(700, 700));
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setTitle("SuperTicTacToe");
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    protected int getDifficulty() {

        int difficulty;
        difficulty = diffucltyBox.getSelectedIndex();

        return difficulty;
    }

}
```

And:

```
public class Problem {

    public void actions() {

        GUI guiObject = new GUI();

        if(guiObject.getDifficulty() == 0) {

            System.out.println("Easy");
        }   

        else if(guiObject.getDifficulty() == 1) {

            System.out.println("Middle");
        }    

        else if(guiObject.getDifficulty() == 2) {

            System.out.println("Hard");
        }    

    }

}
```

And no matter what you select the "Problem - class" will always print out "Easy"

Comment: Is turn a method in a class for the next "screen" of your program? If so, I'd recommend sending the difficulty in the constructor of the next screen.

Comment: Uhm, I have to say, I don't really understand... Should I use the method getDifficulty in the Constructor of the class with the turn method? And then what? Sorry...

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot understand your problem. Please create a [mcve] so we can better understand it and provide a solution.

Comment: Yeah, sorry forgot that. But I imlemented that now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That makes sense. You create 2 instances of GUI. One in your main function and one in the problem class.

For the one instantiated in the main function : you show the frame with setVisible and let the user make a selection in the combobox.

For the other one instantiated in the problem class you never show it on screen, the user can never select something in that instance.

Yet you get the index of the combobox in that instance. It's zero for sure.

You should not instantiate a new one in the problem class but rather pass the shown one as an argument to the problem class eg Problem problemObject = new Problem(this);

Then have it in the problem constructor as an argument rather the creating a new one.